# elasticsearch distance sorting and calculation incorrect and inaccurate

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, geolocation

I'm using elasticsearch for a search functionality on a website. The search must provide a search by distance from a location in an - for example - 25km radius.

That's no problem, I'm using the following elasticsearch query array:

**edit 3**: updated the query with function_score

```
{
    "index": "kasd9i9021profiles",
    "type": "profile",
    "size": 30,
    "from": 0,
    "body": {
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    "linear": {
                        "location": {
                            "origin": "49.449919468911,11.073560787681",
                            "offset": "2km",
                            "scale": "1km"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "published": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "country": "DE"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "25km",
                            "distance_type": "arc",
                            "_cache": true,
                            "location": {
                                "lat": 49.449919468911,
                                "lon": 11.073560787681
                            },
                            "unit": "km"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "rings": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "field": "location",
                "origin": "49.449919468911,11.073560787681",
                "distance_type": "arc",
                "unit": "km",
                "ranges": [
                    {
                        "to": 25
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "distance": {
            "lang": "groovy",
            "params": {
                "lat": 49.449919468911,
                "lon": 11.073560787681
            },
            "script": "doc['location'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "upgrade_sort": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "has_siegel": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "_geo_distance": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 49.449919468911,
                    "lon": 11.073560787681
                },
                "order": "desc",
                "unit": "km"
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    "fields": [
    "_source",
    "distance"
    ]
}
```

The value of "upgrade_sort" can be between 0 and 3.
The value of "has_siegel" can be true or false.

**The problems are:**

1. The results are not sorted by distance
2. The distance in the result is between 0 and ~30km, not between 0 and 25km.

Is that a bug or a wrong query?

**EDIT 1**

Mapping:

```
$params = [
    'index' => $name,
    'body' => [
        'mappings' => [
            'profile' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'name' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'logo_url' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'foto_url' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'info_text' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'cPerson' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'street' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'city' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'country' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'website' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'location' => [
                        'type' => 'geo_point'
                    ],
                    'upgrade_sort' => [
                        'type' => 'integer'
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Results: For privacy reasons I can not publish the full results. Here are the distance details:

**EDIT 2**

Coordinates addet

```
distance: 9,82km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 3
lon: 10.988270100000022
lat: 49.4724229

distance: 10,87km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 2
lon: 10.980907500000058
lat: 49.4808363

distance: 15,71km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 1
lon: 11.017770000000041
lat: 49.5795

distance: 0,15km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.072768300000007
lat: 49.4488594

distance: 0,32km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.07072740000001
lat: 49.44968069999999

distance: 0,32km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.07072740000001
lat: 49.44968069999999

distance: 0,47km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.077651400000036
lat: 49.4487752

distance: 0,60km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.078965499999981
lat: 49.4501188

distance: 0,61km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.078960000000052
lat: 49.45074

distance: 0,56km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.076950099999976
lat: 49.4536002

distance: 0,83km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.080846599999973
lat: 49.4483038

distance: 0,70km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.07790239999997
lat: 49.45442389999999

distance: 0,70km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.07790239999997
lat: 49.45442389999999

distance: 0,94km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.065464399999996
lat: 49.4475953

distance: 0,72km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.075771300000042
lat: 49.4560251

distance: 1,14km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.066973200000007
lat: 49.4578074

distance: 1,40km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.084297399999969
lat: 49.4563874

distance: 1,23km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.077985799999965
lat: 49.4397852

distance: 1,41km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.081709400000022
lat: 49.440276

distance: 1,51km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.067300100000011
lat: 49.4619894

distance: 2,48km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.092409999999973
lat: 49.4618

distance: 3,65km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.104663200000005
lat: 49.4602779

distance: 3,74km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.100480000000061
lat: 49.47002

distance: 4,12km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.043360000000007
lat: 49.42859

distance: 4,16km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.100729999999999
lat: 49.47564

distance: 5,61km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.032510600000023
lat: 49.4207607

distance: 5,41km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.093795699999987
lat: 49.4057095

distance: 6,60km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.033873800000038
lat: 49.4058283

distance: 7,51km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.016179100000045
lat: 49.4143705

distance: 7,49km
has_siegel: 0
upgrade_sort: 0
lon: 11.130335599999967
lat: 49.41382410000001
```

Comment: Did you gave a try ?

Comment: could you try sorting first by `distance` and then by `upgrade sort` and `has_siegel`?

Comment: That's not a solution because it is a requirement to sort first by `upgrade_sort` and `has_siegel`.

Comment: Any chance for a reproduceable usecase? (mapping, data sample, query and results) In github you will probably get the same question.

Comment: I just added more details to the questen.

Comment: Take a look of the results: 0,32km < 0,47km < 0,60km < 0,61km < 0,56km ? Not really!

Comment: @AntonDachauer I'm assuming that by privacy you refer to the actual coordinates that you cannot share?

Comment: have you defined explicit mapping for `has_siegel`? also could you please try sorting **just by distance** and confirm results are still wrong?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I just added the coordinates.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I just tried it sorting only by distance and I got the same wrong results.

Comment: It seems Adrien solved the problem. I would appreciate if you can post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution: Chaning `doc['location'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)` to `doc['location'].arcDistanceInKm(lat,lon)`

That isn't easy to find in the documentation, but the developers of elasticsearch will update it: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15616

Answer (score 0):

Your filter only excludes results that are not within the 25km radius circle. If you want to sort the results by distance you must use a [function score query with a decay function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_supported_decay_functions).

For the distance, if you want it to be more accurate, as mentioned in the doc you should use [the arc distance_type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geo-distance.html#_faster_geo_distance_calculations).

Comment: I jus updated the query in my post with function score query.